# MySQL query add limit on relation table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables linked with OneToMany. Table **books** and table **authors**. Each author has many books.
I want to fetch a list of books, but for each author, only 10 books.

How to achieve that?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: mysql -V gives:

mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.28-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` for example:

```
select *
from (
  select *, row_number() over(partition by author_id order by title) as rn
  from book
) x
where rn <= 10
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me give it a try :)

Comment: If anyone interested:

SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY author_id ORDER BY expire_date IS NULL DESC, expire_date DESC) AS max_books_per_author FROM book) b INNER JOIN author a ON b.author_id = a.id WHERE max_books_per_author <= 10 AND a.status = 'active';